# Maven duplicated jar files in eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, file, maven, jar

I have a problem with duplicated jar files in my eclipse project. I'm using Maven 3.5.2 and Java 1.7. The jar files are in Maven Dependencies, and duplicated files are also outside of this package.
Here is a screen from my project explorer:
[screen](http://79.96.4.173/mmorawski/2015-02-16_1052.png)

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What files are duplicated? Have you checked on command line via `mvn dependency:tree` etc? BTW: I assume you mean Maven 3.2.5 instead of Maven 3.5.2..

Comment: My problem is that jar files are in Maven Dependency and outside of  this in project explorore, at screen u can see how it looks :) I mean Maven 3.2.5

Comment: I assume you have used `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to get this project into Eclipse? If yes please use the default via m2e import instead.

Comment: yes i used mvn eclipse:eclipse, how to make it via m2e :) ?